# Why data is not send by form submitting (zf2 forms + filters)?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-filter, zend-form2, zend-inputfilter

I have problem:

When I fill in form and pressing add button page is reloaded, but no data is added to the database.

Code of `NewsController`, `add` action is below:

```
public function addAction() {
    $form = new AddNewsForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add1');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        var_dump($form->isValid());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            echo "form is valid";
            $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

            $blogpost = new NewsItem();

            $blogpost->exchangeArray($form->getData());

            $blogpost->setCreated(time());
            $blogpost->setUserId(0);

            $objectManager->persist($blogpost);
            $objectManager->flush();

            // Redirect to list of blogposts
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('news');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Class `AddNewsForm` is included as `use \News\Form\AddNewsForm as AddNewsForm;` above.

I tried to debug my code and realized, that `$form->isValid()` return false all time. I tried to fill in all fields of form — it says that form is not valid. If not all fields are filled in it false too.

The problem is with validation, I think, so I will add here how I assing filter to the form. This is how I assing filter to my form:

```
$this->setInputFilter(new AddNewsInputFilter());
```

Class `AddNewsInputFilter` is included by this:

```
use \News\Form\AddNewsInputFilter as AddNewsInputFilter;
```

I don't think it is good to paste there ~100 lines of code, so I will just give a link to files in my github repo (full code of controllers/files available here):

- [AddNewsForm.php](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/test/blob/master/src/News/Form/AddNewsForm.php) — file, where I create the form
- [AddNewsInputFilter.php](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/test/blob/master/src/News/Form/AddNewsInputFilter.php) — file, where I set fil
- [NewsController.php](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/test/blob/master/src/News/Controller/NewsController.php) — file, controller, where I call created form
- [Repository link](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/test) — root dir of my module

So the problem is that `$form->isValid();` doesn't show is form valid or not properly and I don't know why. Note, that request is getting properly and first condition is passed (but second is not passed). It is the problem, thats why I am writing here.

How I can solve it?

Thanks is advance!

Comment: try `$form->getMessages()` and `$form->getInputFilter()->getMessages()` in controller(after calling `$form->isValid()`) or view .

see what error you getting and on witch element ?

Comment: @Exlord I had already tried getMessage, but it didn't helped me. It shows nothing. I will try 2nd method, you mentioned in the comment, later, when it will be possible. I didn't understand why I have to use it after isValid function. I can't use it inside of condition, because I'll never be there at the moment. Did you mean in condition or after it?

Comment: `getMessages()` will be empty if `$form->isValid()` has not been called yet, you have a `var_dump($form->isValid());` in the code put `getMessages()` after that.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will try it a bit later.

Comment: @Exlord, argh!!! I tried it! Firstly, I set data to the form, after that doing `var_dump($form->isValid());` and `$form->getMessages();`. No messages were displayed. Can't past much code here, so I will just show image: [click me](http://i.gyazo.com/d95e476fd56ab4a0829aa51781abf4f9.png)

Comment: @Exlord. The problem was in article, where I was reading how to work with forms. I generated input with type `Zend\Form\Element\Csrf`, but didn't output him. I realized this, after I did `var_dump($form->getMessages());`. I thougth it will work using `$form->getMessages()` but I had to use `var_dump($form->getMessages());`. Now all working. Can you summarize all this information so I can accept your answer and vote it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `var_dump($form->getMessages())` and `var_dump($form->getInputFilter()->getMessages())` in controller(after calling $form->isValid()) or in view . see what error you getting and on witch element ?

NOTICE : `getMessages()` will be empty if `$form->isValid()` has not been called yet,

UPDATE : do this in controller :

```
var_dump($form->isValid());
var_dump($form->getMessages())
var_dump($form->getInputFilter()->getMessages())
```